# Understanding the derivation of the PDF of a two-point mixed distribution from its CDF

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> A random variable $X$ has the cumulative distribution function
> $$\begin{cases}
> 0 & x<1 \\
> \dfrac{x^2-2x+2}{2} & 1 \le x<2 \\
> 1 & x\ge 2
> \end{cases}$$
> Calculate $E[X]$.

The answer uses the following pdf to get $E[X]$:
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2} & x=1 \\
x-1 & 1 < x<2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The book I am reading doesn't have much (any!) information on two-point mixed distributions and I want to make sure that I understand how this PDF was derived from the CDF. My understanding so far is that firstly, we need to figure out from the CDF that $X$ follows a mixed distribution. Note that $F(1) = 1/2 \ne 0$, which indicates that there is a jump in the CDF of $X$ at $x=1$. Since $X$ is continuous from $1<x<2$, $X$ must follow a two-point mixed distribution. Now, the magnitude of the jump in the graph is $\frac{1}{2}-0 = \frac{1}{2}$ which gives $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ if $x=1$. The rest of the pdf can be obtained using routine computations. Finally, we need to compute the probabilistic "weights" to get to the CDF. Clearly, the "weight" for the discrete part is $\frac{1}{2}$, so the "weight" for the continuous part must be $1-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$, and we have

$$E[X] = \int_1^2 (x-1) \cdot x dx + \text{Weight for the discrete part} \cdot 1 = \int_1^2 x(x-1) dx + P[X=1] \cdot 1$$
$$= \int_1^2 x(x-1) dx + \frac{1}{2}$$

which gives the correct answer. However, I am more interested in learning whether my process for obtaining the answer (which was based mostly on deduction and intuition) is correct. Can someone please critique my post? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote there isn't a PDF, since it doesn't have integral $1$. There isn't really a PDF in the usual sense at all, because there is a discrete part.

A PDF for this distribution is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \delta(x-1) + (x-1) 1_{(1,2)}(x)$. Here $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta "function", which is not really a function in the same way you are used to. This funny $1$ notation is defined by

$$1_A(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in A \\
0 & x \not \in A \end{cases}$$

One can evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \left ( \frac{1}{2} \delta(x-1) + (x-1) 1_{(1,2)}(x) \right ) dx$ to get the expectation. To do that, the delta function term winds up giving you $\left. \frac{1}{2} x \right |_{x=1}=\frac{1}{2}$, while the other term gives you $\int_1^2 x(x-1) dx$.

Note that the PDF on $(1,2)$ is in fact $x-1$: there is no need for an extra factor of $1/2$ because $\int_1^2 (x-1) dx$ is already $1/2$.

Comment: One thing worth noting: this question is an actuarial exam question from the sample questions provided for exam P in probability. Very few, if any, who study the sample questions will be aware of the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @Clarinetist Yeah I have a bad habit of trying to stick as close to the person asking the question is trying to do as possible rather than adapting to what I expect they should be doing. I am trying to come up with a non-confusing way to explain it without the use of the delta function, but the best thing I am coming up with involves some fiddling with conditioning that seems a bit confusing to me (there are some extra factors to juggle that ultimately cancel out anyway). If you have a suggestion for improving the answer I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: @Clarinetist You're right, I am not aware of the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your response. I edited the continuous integral part, you were right about that, there should be a $x$ instead of $1/2$. Is there a simpler, perhaps less rigorous, way of deriving the PDF from the CDF?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson There is no actual way to make sense of the PDF without the Dirac delta function. (You can call it something else, but if you do, you will be reinventing the wheel.) There is a way to get the expectation without writing down the PDF, though. What that way is basically boils down to what you did. A slightly more sophisticated way would be to use the total expectation formula, conditioning on whether the value is drawn from the discrete part or from the continuous part, but this ultimately boils down to the same thing you did.

Comment: @Ian Then, was I correct in thinking that $P[X=1]$ is equal to the magnitude of the jump in the graph of CDF at $x=1$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Yes, that's actually a general thing, even when talking about considerably weirder distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right (ignoring the measure-theoretic technicalities), and will serve in the vast majority (if not all) situations you will run into with actuarial exam problems.

An alternate solution to consider is as follows: let $X$ be a non-negative random variable (i.e., $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0) = 1$) with CDF $F(x)$. Let $a \geq 0$ be  the largest value such that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq a) = 1$. Then assuming it exists, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X^k] = k\left\{a^k + \int_{a}^{\infty}x^{k-1}\left[1-F(x) \right]\text{ d}x\right\}$$
This formula works whether your random variable $X$ is discrete, continuous, or mixed. It is a consequence of the "Darth Vader Rule" coined by [Muldowney, Ostaszewski and Wojdows (2012)](https://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/1030150905-M-O-W.pdf).

One can observe through the CDF that $a = 1$ is the largest value such that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 1) = 1$. Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^1] &= \mathbb{E}[X] \\
&= 1\left\{1^1 + \int_{1}^{\infty}x^{1-1}\left[1-F(x) \right]\text{ d}x\right\} \\
&= 1 + \int_{1}^{\infty}\left[1 - F(x)\right]\text{ d}x\text{.}
\end{align}$$
We next observe that
$$1 - F(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & x < 1 \\
1 - \dfrac{x^2 - 2x + 2}{2}, & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
0, & x \geq 2
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
1, & x < 1 \\
\dfrac{- x^2 + 2x}{2}, & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
0, & x \geq 2 
\end{cases}$$
thus
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left[1 - F(x)\right]\text{ d}x = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}(- x^2 + 2x)\text{ d}x = \dfrac{1}{3}$$
leading to
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 1 + \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{4}{3}\text{.}$$

---

The formula I provided above is often written more compactly as
$$\mathbb{E}[X^k] = \int_{0}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}[1 - F(x)]\text{ d}x$$
and you can show this will yield an equivalent answer to the above. However, note this only applies to **non-negative random variables**.

Comment: That's very interesting to know, thanks. For what it's worth, it fueled my desire to eventually study measure-theoretic probability!